# How to re-emit a Subject several times in a Foreach loop?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subject

I'm trying to subscribe a Subject, which would be re-emited several times in a forEach. But I only got one subscription, actually 7 times is expected.

I tried to delay some times to execute the "next()" method with setTimeOut. But it doesn't work.
Angular Cli: 6.2.9
Node: 10.15.3
OS: win32 x64
rxjs: 6.2.2
typescript: 2.7.2

```
private selectedVersion$: Subject<LeadTimeVersion> = new Subject<LeadTimeVersion>();
productLineId: string;
nodes: LeadTimeNode[] =[];
filterNodes: LeadTimeNode[];
versions: LeadTimeVersion[];
constructor( private leadTimeService: LeadTimeService) { }
ngOnInit() {

...

    let counter = 0;
    this.selectedVersion$.pipe(
      switchMap(v => this.leadTimeService.getLeadTimeVersionData(this.productLineId, v.id)),
      takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)
    ).subscribe(x => {
        this.nodes = mergeArray(this.nodes, x.nodes);
        counter++;
        if(counter === this.versions.length){
          this.filterTables('');
        }
    });

    this.leadTimeService.selectedLeadTimeWorkbench$.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)
    ).subscribe(x => {
      this.productLineId = x.id;
      this.versions = x.workingVersions;

      this.versions.forEach(v => {

        this.selectedVersion$.next(v);
      })

    });

  }
```

Comment: probably better to emit the array object at one go

Comment: Change `switchMap` to `mergeMap`. `switchMap` is cancelling your previous API response and emitting only the latest value of the API.

Comment: @user2216584, thanks, it works

Comment: if the answers above are solving your issue then you should post it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change switchMap to mergeMap. switchMap is cancelling your previous API response and emitting only the latest value of the API. 
The answer above works, which is answered by @user2216584. Thanks.